# Selenium python checkbox by span class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have an issue with checkbox check in selenium python, I want to make not exact xpath, but something like I did earlier in the code :
`browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Dalej')]").click()`
but it was in differend coding

exact Xpath of checkbox:
`/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/fieldset/label/span[1]`

checkbox is in:`<span class="o-ci"></span>`

I want to make some simple find element click, that not include exact XPATH, because I want to test page (source, divs can change, I want to secure my scrpt for that, and lock on something elese)

source code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend class="u-acc-hide">PotwierdÅº, Å¼e akceptujesz regulamin i wyraÅ¼asz wszystkie zgody
            </legend>
    <label class="o-checkbox  ">
        <input type="checkbox" data-type="master" class="" name="agreement-master" aria-required="false">
            <span class="o-ci"></span>
            <span class="o-ci-label">
                Tak
                </span>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: From you question and code sample I have no idea for what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match the `<input type="checkbox">` which is before the `<span class="o-ci">` you could go for something like:

```
//span[@class='o-ci']/preceding-sibling::input
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) in general and [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) in particular
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)